# Get information of every uploaded file

Tags: android, file, linux-kernel, upload, kernel

I would like to save the information (file name, size, bytes) of any uploaded file from any application to my application. I skimmed through AOSP repo a little bit but couldn't find any endpoint to fetch data. Do you know how can I achieve that desired result?

Comment: Fortunately, this is not possible in general, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Ordinary apps cannot spy on other apps' Internet access.

Comment: it is a bit unclear , what do you mean by  " uploaded file from any application to my application"